# Null-conditional operator evaluates to bool not to bool? as expected

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0

I've just upgraded from VS 2010 to 2015. I like the new [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn986595.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) which is also known as null-propagation. This enables to simplify your code, for example:

```
string firstCustomerName = customers?[0].Name; // null if customers or the first customer is null
```

another one:

```
int? count = customers?[0]?.Orders?.Count();  // null if customers, the first customer, or Orders is null
```

which returns a `Nullable<int>` even if `Enumerable.Count` returns an `int` to differentiate between a valid count and any `nulls` before. That's quite intuitive and very useful.

But why does this compile and work as expected (it returns `false`):

```
string text = null;
bool contains = text?.IndexOf("Foo", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

It should either return `bool?` (which it does not) or not compile.

Comment: Whoops, i think i've got it myself, you can rewrite it: `int? indexof = text?.IndexOf("Foo", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase); bool contains = indexof >= 0;`

Comment: I'd vote for a `?>=` operator. :)

Comment: @DStanley: so one which includes other [operator categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx) than primary? Would do more harm than good.

Comment: Tangential, but if you do `customers?[0]?.Orders?.Count() ?? 0`, you will get an `int`. This may or may not be helpful to you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What you actually have is

```
string text = null;
int? index = text?.IndexOf("Foo", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
bool contains = index >= 0;
```

and `int? >= int` is perfectly legal.

The reason it was split there is [the documentation for the operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) states *"If one operation in a chain of conditional member access and index operation returns null, then the rest of the chain’s execution stops. Other operations with lower precedence in the expression continue."* That means `.?` will only evaluate things with the same precedence or higher before it "creates a value".

If you look at [the order of operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) you will see that "Relational and Type-testing Operators" are much lower in the list so the value will be created before the `>=` is applied.

---

**UPDATE:** Because it was brought up in the comments, here is the C# 5 spec section on how the `>=` and other operators behave when dealing with a nullable value. I could not find a document for C# 6.

> ## 7.3.7 Lifted operators
>
> **Lifted operators** permit predefined and user-defined operators that operate on non-nullable value types to also be used with nullable
>   forms of those types. Lifted operators are constructed from predefined
>   and user-defined operators that meet certain requirements, as
>   described in the following:
>
> - For the unary operators
>        `+  ++  -  --  !  ~`
>
>   a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand and result types are both non-nullable value types. The lifted form is
>     constructed by adding a single ? modifier to the operand and result
>     types. The lifted operator produces a null value if the operand is
>     null. Otherwise, the lifted operator unwraps the operand, applies the
>     underlying operator, and wraps the result.
> - For the binary operators
>     `+  -  *  /  %  &  |  ^  <<  >>`
>
>   a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand and result types
>     are all non-nullable value types. The lifted form is constructed by
>     adding a single ? modifier to each operand and result type. The lifted
>     operator produces a null value if one or both operands are null (an
>     exception being the & and | operators of the bool? type, as described
>     in §7.11.3). Otherwise, the lifted operator unwraps the operands,
>     applies the underlying operator, and wraps the result.
> - For the equality operators
>     `==  !=`
>
>   a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both
>     non-nullable value types and if the result type is bool. The lifted
>     form is constructed by adding a single ? modifier to each operand
>     type. The lifted operator considers two null values equal, and a null
>     value unequal to any non-null value. If both operands are non-null,
>     the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying
>     operator to produce the bool result.
> - For the relational operators
>     `<  >  <=  >=`
>
>   a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is bool. The lifted
>     form is constructed by adding a single ? modifier to each operand
>     type. The lifted operator produces the value false if one or both
>     operands are null. Otherwise, the lifted operator unwraps the operands
>     and applies the underlying operator to produce the bool result.

Comment: For those of us without much knowledge in C#, what is the behavior of the operator `>=` when the `Nullable` is actually null?

Comment: @njzk2 in simple terms, if either side or both sides of the `>=` are null it will always return false. See my update for the full spec.

Answer (score 4):

If you use this code, and hover over `x`, you see that `x` is a `int?`:

```
var x = text?.IndexOf("Foo", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
bool contains = x >= 0;
```

So the typing is still correct.

Then lets look into `x >= 0`: that is a `int? >= int`. Appearantly there is an operator between the nullable and non-nullable structs. That is why it works.

If you look at the IL, you will see it actually calls `HasValue` and `GetValueOrDefault()`. I guess there is an operator doing this, but I couldn't find it in the reference source, so it should be in the CLR or compiler:

```
instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::GetValueOrDefault()

...
instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::get_HasValue()
```

Comment: True, but it could have been that the null-conditional operator would include the `>=` operator which would return a `bool?`. But i guess that this is meant with [_"other operations with lower precedence in the expression continue"_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).