# Comparing two null nullables

Tags: c#, nullable, lifted-operators

The C# 5.0 spec reads in chapter 7.1.3

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx

> The lifted operator produces the value `false` if one **or both** operands are `null`.

However testing and also this MSDN link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy(v=vs.100).aspx

```
int? num1 = 10;
int? num2 = null;

// Change the value of num1, so that both num1 and num2 are null.
num1 = null;
if (num1 == num2)
{
  // The equality comparison returns true when both operands are null.
  Console.WriteLine("num1 == num2 returns true when the value of each is null");
}

/* Output:
 * num1 == num2 returns true when the value of each is null
 */
```

shows that comparing two nullable values that are both `null` returns `true`.

It makes sense but it contradicts the sentence from the spec, does it not?

Comment: I found this in chapter 7.3.7. Notice this is for `binary operators`. The very next section talks about `equality operators`, which includes `==`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Null-conditional operator evaluates to bool not to bool? as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277102/null-conditional-operator-evaluates-to-bool-not-to-bool-as-expected)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dont mix, this is about different types of operators.

> • For the equality operators
>   ==  !=
>   a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is bool. The lifted form is constructed by adding a single ? modifier to each operand type. **The lifted operator considers two null values equal**, and a null value unequal to any non-null value. If both operands are non-null, the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying operator to produce the bool result.
>
> •  For the relational operators
>   <  >  <=  >=
>   a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is bool. The lifted form is constructed by adding a single ? modifier to each operand type. **The lifted operator produces the value false if one or both operands are null**. Otherwise, the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying operator to produce the bool result.

Answer (score 4):

Spec later says that

> • For the equality operators
>   ==  != a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is bool. The
>   lifted form is constructed by adding a single ? modifier to each
>   operand type. **The lifted operator considers two null values equal, and
>   a null value unequal to any non-null value**. If both operands are
>   non-null, the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the
>   underlying operator to produce the bool result.

Comment: Ohh, you was a first one, you win :D